# AJAX load in the same page not in popUp

Tags: php, html, ajax

I try to load the page links in popup... after adding this script the page load in the bottom of the page ... how to open it in popup ???

```
$('a[rel="ajax:jmodal"]').click(function(event) {

 $.ajax({

url: $(this).attr('href'),

success: function(newHTML, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  $(newHTML).appendTo('body').jmodal();
},

error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  // Handle AJAX errors
}

// More AJAX customization goes here.

 });

return false;
});
```

Comment: You're appending to the body, not the modal.

Comment: @JayBlanchard when i add model instead of body it didn't work

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you try with with Bootstrap dialog. See
[Link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

Comment: the problem is not with the plugin he is using, he is not appending the value properly.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't think she has the min privilege to comment yet

Comment: The poster doesn't @Vincent, which is why I gave her the link. Outside of that, this does not answer the question.

Comment: "Just use Bootstrap!" is the new ["Just use Jquery!"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/180262)

Comment: @Vincent how can i append the value properly ??

Comment: @MohamedHesham append it to the element which you have inside your modal(div), you must have selected an element which has to be rendered as a modal popup ?

Comment: @Vincent yes i already have one in the footer   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>